# Problems with dotvvm Validation

Tags: dotvvm

Reviewing the documentation for using the Validator

> If you want to validate some property, just use standard attributes
>   from the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations namespace. DotVVM can
>   translate some validation rules into javascript, so the validation can
>   be executed also on the client side.

Then I developed the following code:

```
using System;
using DotVVM.Framework.ViewModel;
using APP_MIS_FACTURAS.Models;
using System.Web;
using DotVVM.Framework.Controls.Bootstrap;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace APP_MIS_FACTURAS.ViewModels
{
    public class InicioViewModel : DotvvmViewModelBase
    {

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "No se indica la contraseña del usuario")]
        public string usuario { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }

    }
}
```

But I get the following error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Required' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   APP_MIS_FACTURAS    C:\Users\leojfn\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\Cystem\APP_MIS_FACTURAS\APP_MIS_FACTURAS\ViewModels\InicioViewModel.cs  45  Active

I do not know if I need to import some specific library or I need to install something NuGetPackage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click the project in the Solution Explorer window, choose Add Reference and select `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`. 
It is not referenced by default, however it is included in .NET Framework.